# Php foreach sorting with three variables

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to use a foreach loop to print out links which are sorted after one of the three variables in an array, `$term->description`. The value of `$term->name` is the text inside the link element. How could I add a href attribute to a link by using the third variable `$term->slug` in the same foreach loop? I have tried to make two separate arrays and use `array_combine`, but to no avail.

Here is the code working for two variables. To make things clear I have simply added `$term->slug` added at its desired location.

```
$terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );
$a = array();
foreach ($terms as $term ) : 
    $a[] = array( $term->name, $term->description, $term->slug);
endforeach; 


// print_r($a); 
// Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Los Angeles [1] => City [2] => los-angeles ) [1] => Array ( [0] => San Francisco [1] => City [2] => san-francisco ) [2] => Array ( [0] => San Diego [1] => City [2] => san-diego ) [3] => Array ( [0] => United States [1] => Country [2] => united-states ) ) 

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    $return[$value[1]][] = $value[0];
}   

foreach ($return as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.": <span class='tags'><a href='$term->slug'>".implode('</a></span>,<span class="tags"><a href="$term->slug">', $value)."</a></span>";
}

// Outputs:
// City: Los Angeles  San Fransisco  San Diego
// Country: United States
```

Comment: Can you give me the desired html output. $term->slug will not work as $term is in first foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code :**

```
<?php
  error_reporting('E_ALL');

  $a = Array(Array("Los Angeles","City","los-angeles"),Array("San Francisco","City","san-francisco"),Array("San Diego","City","san-diego"),Array("United States","Country","united-states"));

  foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
      $return[$value[1]][] = array("name"=>$value[0],"slug"=>$value[2]);
  }   


  foreach ($return as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.":";
      foreach($value as $newvalue){
       echo '<span class="tags"><a href="'.$newvalue["slug"].'">'.$newvalue["name"].'</a>&nbsp;</span>';
    }
    echo "<br>";
  }
```

**Output:**

```
City:<span class="tags"></span><a href="los-angeles">Los Angeles</a>&nbsp;<span class="tags"></span><a href="san-francisco">San Francisco</a>&nbsp;<span class="tags"></span><a href="san-diego">San Diego</a>&nbsp;<br>Country:<span class="tags"></span><a href="united-states">United States</a>&nbsp;<br>
```

Comment: Great answer. It didn't occur to me how straightforward it was to nest another foreach loop inside the first one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to help always.